# Reference generator. How can I collect users input into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm new to Python and I have started my first project. I want to make a reference generator. However, I have faced a problem with authors name. Right now my code can accept and obtain only one author (name and surname), but I want it to be able to collect a few authors. I am struggling to find a logic that will help me to collect few authors names and save them into a list.

I will try to explain it with an example:

```
authors_name = input('Enter authors name: ')
question = input('Add another author? [Yes | No]: ')

while question.lower() = 'yes':
new_author = input('Enter authors name: ')
```

This is the part where I'm stuck. How can I make my program to remember the first entered name and the names that will come after that? I suppose I should use lists or smthng.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use a list `authors = []` and `append` what you need to the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
list_of_authors = []
question = lambda: input('Add another author? [Yes | No]: ').lower()

while True:
    author_name = input("Enter author name: ")
    list_of_authors += [author_name]
    if question() == "no":
        break
```

Comment: Did you try that?  It won't do what you think it does.

Comment: Of course, I tried, it works correctly.

Comment: @OlehYarosh sorry for doubting you.

Comment: @TimRoberts it works fine 

Comment: `list_of_authors += [author_name]` is a very awkward way of writing `list_of_authors.append(author_name)`. I also wouldn't use a lambda function for the prompt to run again, but I might put the prompt string in a variable so the `input(again_prompt).lower() == "no"` line wouldn't need to be too long.

Answer (score 0):

It's unfriendly to require people to answer an extra question.  Just keep asking for more names until they press "enter".

```
print( "Press enter to stop entering names." )
authors = []
while True:
    authors_name = input('Enter authors name: ')
    if not authors_name:
        break
    authors.append( authors_name )

print( "The list I got was", authors )
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach:

```
list_of_authors = []
answer = input('Add author? [Yes | No]: ').lower()
while True:
    if answer == "yes":
        author_name = input("Enter author name: ")
        list_of_authors += [author_name]
    elif answer == "no":
        break
    else:
        print ('Invalid input..please select either yes or no')
        continue
    answer = input('Add another author? [Yes | No]: ').lower()
print (f'Authors: {list_of_authors}')
```

Output:

```
Add author? [Yes | No]: yes
Enter author name: bhagyesh
Add another author? [Yes | No]: yes
Enter author name: dudhediya
Add another author? [Yes | No]: no
Authors: ['bhagyesh', 'dudhediya']
```